# Get all items with specific fields without query - SharePoint Client Object Model

Tags: development, client-object-model

Is it possible to get all items from a single list (getting specific fields) without using a `CamlQuery`? If I try to use `context.Load(oList, ...)`, I can't use the `Include` method as the `List` class doesn't implement the `Include` method.

I've seen examples that use a `ListCollection`, but I'm only using one list.

Comment: do you want to get all list items with specific fields? not returning the fields but rather the items themselfs?

Comment: Yes, the items, but only with certain columns/fields.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong you can use empty CamlQuery.

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View/>";
```

For performance issue the common practice is to use view fields to reduce response data.

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = 
    @"<View>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name='PartLookup' LookupId='TRUE' />
          <FieldRef Name='PartLookupSKU' />
          <FieldRef Name='PartLookupTitle' />
          <FieldRef Name='PartLookupDescription' />
          <FieldRef Name='BinNumber' />
          <FieldRef Name='Quantity' />
        </ViewFields>
      </View>";
```

Comment: Yes, so it seems you can't avoid the CamlQuery when fetching specific fields?

Comment: I think - yes :)

Comment: Don't forget about the CreateAllItemsQuery static function on the CamlQuery object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.createallitemsquery.aspx